# two page enconding needed for differents purpose

Tags: jquery-ui, encoding, datepicker

the scenario is like this :

datepicker jquery ui in french needs the page to be encoded iso (because with utf , there are some french character that are not well displayed)

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

and i have some arabic data that i need to store in the database, for this the page must be encoded in utf_8

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

data is sent via ajax

what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I believe you should always publish with UTF-8.  But you need to make sure that all declared encodings agree.  For example, for HTML, any encoding declared in a `<meta>` tag should agree with the actual `Content-type` HTTP header.

The only reason I can think of to publish in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 is if you have a client that you cannot change that requires this encoding.  But even in that case, hopefully you would be able to use a `User-Agent` request header to identify this client and serve ISO-8859-1 only to that client.

Comment: i publish with utf_8 , but having this , i have some problems with french accented character like (é) , this characters are well displayed with iso encoding.

Comment: more precisely , the problem with this character is just with datepicker of jquery , it means , in other places in the page , there is no problem

Comment: If you mean that the datepicker is producing é and others in ISO-8859-1 into the document, then you'll need to find a way to change its encoding as well.  Everything has to be consistent.  Sorry, I'm not experienced with jquery.

Comment: the problem is due to js file that is used normally to make the jquery datepicker in french

Comment: I'm not clear: are you saying the .js source file is being delivered to the browser in ISO-8859-1 encoding, or is it causing the browser to load data that is delivered in ISO-8859-1?  Either way, try to find a way to change that to UTF-8.  Everything UTF-8.